# Why can't get Backbone collection models when using a defined function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Let's say we have an instance of a given collection (url is specified inside the collection definition), for example :

```
var collection = new SomeCollection(),
    async = collection.fetch();
```

When i use an anonymous callback inside `done` method it is working just fine, like the following example :

```
async.done(function(){
    console.log('models are : ',collection.models)    
});
```

But when i define a **global function** and try to use it instead of the previous done callback, to organize the code little bit, i get an empty models array :

```
function done(collection){
   console.log('models are : ',collection.models) 
} 


async.done(done(collection));
```

What is exactly the problem here ? 
Why is it taking the collection state before the fetch call ?

**Note :** I've tried also to use `.bind`,`.call`,`.apply` but it is **not working !**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async.done takes function as an argument. The problem is you actually pass the result of function as an argument to async.done. You need to pass function as an argument without applying it.

Try the following code:

```
function done(collection){
  console.log('models are : ',collection.models) 
} 

function success(collection){
  console.log('response: ',collection) 
}     

var collection = new SomeCollection(),
async = collection.fetch();

// you can use success or done method
// you can bind collection argument by yourself
async.success(success);
async.done(done.bind(this, collection));
```

Comment: But if i don't provide collection as  a parameter then it is not defined inside the done function ! so i get the nice ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined(…)`` error

Comment: If you want to pass some parameter or this value to callback function you can take advantage of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method. I've updated my answer

Comment: You can try to use success method on your async object. Then you don't need the bind method because collection is passed automatically to success method.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var collection = new SomeCollection(),
    async = collection.fetch({
        success: done
    });


function done(collection, response, options) {
   console.log('models are : ', collection.models) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the sample code you've provided is that you're not passing `done` method to `then()`, but it's return value as Volodymyr Synytskyi explained in his answer.

---

The jQuery `xhr` object isn't aware of the existence of backbone.js (for example a `parse` method defined in collection/model based on which backbone updates collection/model)

When the request succeeds, it's success callbacks will be fired. There is no guarantee that when these fire, backbone would've finished creating all the models based on the response.

This is why backbone provides a success callback, which will be fired after backbone is done with its activities.

You can pass your global handler as the success callback which will be called with `collection/model`, `response`, `options` as the arguments in that order.

```
function done(collection,response,options){
  console.log('models are : ',collection.models)
}

var collection = new SomeCollection(),
collection.fetch({
 success: done
});
```